# Is tensorflow's session run interface reentrant?

Tags: tensorflow, reentrancy

I'm just wondering if tensorflow's session run interface is reentrant because in my case, multiple threads may access the same session.
btw, I use tensorflow's c++ api.

Answer (score 0):

In the python interface, the same `tf.Session` can be used from different threads with some caution, even though it remains the property of the thread who created it. I suppose the situation is similar in C++.

[From the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session):

> N.B. The default session is a property of the current thread. If you
>   create a new thread, and wish to use the default session in that
>   thread, you must explicitly add a `with sess.as_default():` in that
>   thread's function.
>
> N.B. Entering a `with sess.as_default():` block does not affect the
>   current default graph. If you are using multiple graphs, and
>   `sess.graph` is different from the value of `tf.get_default_graph`, you
>   must explicitly enter a `with sess.graph.as_default():` block to make
>   `sess.graph` the default graph.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer in tensorflow source code.
tensorflow/core/public/session.h, in its comment:

```
// A Session allows concurrent calls to Run(), though a Session must
/// be created / extended by a single thread.
///
/// Only one thread must call Close(), and Close() must only be called
/// after all other calls to Run() have returned.
```